# Angular：カスタムしたdirectiveを動的にタグに埋め込みたい

Tags: typescript, angular5

この質問はhttps://teratail.com/questions/142007にも投稿しています。
質問に回答がつかなかった為、こちらにも投稿させてもらいました。質問内容は下記です。

Angular6で、複数の画面で共通のdirectiveを使おうと思っています。
複数のプログラマーがテンプレートに個々にdirectiveを埋め込むと抜け漏れが発生するので、
name="corp_name"のinputタグの場合、必ず"HanToZen"というdirectiveを埋め込む様に
ngOnInitで実装したいのですが、うまくいきません。

もしかすると、setAttributeした後にテンプレートをコンパイルしなおさないといけないのかと思い、現在はその方向で調べています。
どなたかご教授頂けるととても助かります。どうぞよろしくお願いします。

※directiveで呼んでいるconvertHAN2ZENは受け取った文字列の半角文字を全角に変換するだけの関数です。
directiveが有効になる方法が分かれば、処理の内容は何でもいいので省略させて頂きました。

試したコードは下記です。

directive-test.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-directive-test',
  templateUrl: './directive-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./directive-test.component.css']
})
export class DirectiveTestComponent implements OnInit {

  element: HTMLElement;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.element = el.nativeElement;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    // 単純にHTMLelementにZenToHanをsetしてみると、DOMは期待通りになるのですがdirectiveが動きませんでした
    var input = this.element.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) { 
      if ( input[i].getAttribute("name")  === "corp_name") { 
        input[i].setAttribute("HanToZen","");
      }
    }

    // Renderer2でcreateも試してみましたが、HTMLelementにsetAttributeした時と結果は同じでした
    var rendInput = this.renderer.createElement('input');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(rendInput, 'name', 'corp_name2');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(rendInput, 'HanToZen', '');
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.element, rendInput);
  }
}
```

han-to-zen.directive.ts

```
import {OnInit, Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
import { convertHAN2ZEN } from "./util";

@Directive({
  selector: '[HanToZen]'
})
export class HanToZenDirective implements OnInit {

  private element: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
  ) {
    this.element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.element.value = convertHAN2ZEN(this.element.value);
  }

  @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
  onBlur(value){
    this.element.value = convertHAN2ZEN(value);
  }
}
```

directive-test.component.html

```
<h2>Directive Test</h2>  
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
  <!-- firstのHanToZenは問題なく動作する -->
  <input name="first" [(ngModel)]="first" HanToZen>
  <!-- corp_nameにsetAttributeしたHanToZenは動作しない -->
  <input name="corp_name" value='100'  [(ngModel)]="corp_name" >
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

＜動作環境＞

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.3
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.5
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.3 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                      6.1.3
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.5
@schematics/angular               0.7.3 (cli-only)
@schematics/update                0.7.3 (cli-only)
rxjs                              6.2.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/142007

Comment: マルチポストの指摘有難うございます。こういったサイトへの複数投稿がマルチポストとしてマナー違反になると知りませんでしたので、勉強になりました。質問した両方のサイトにマルチポストしている事を記載しておきます。

Comment: ご自分の質問に自己回答ができます。回答にはリンクではなく内容を記入してください。

Comment: またまたご指摘有難うございます。作法を知らずに質問を投稿してしまい、申し訳ありません。回答をまとめて自己回答として投稿したいと思います。リンクを貼ったコメントは消しておきます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この質問はhttps://teratail.com/questions/142007にも投稿し、有用な回答を得られたので、こちらにも記載し回答済みとします。
（下記の内容はteratailユーザー：keisukehさんの回答を元にしています）

質問に対する回答は２つです。

> **1.ngOnInitでDOMにdirectiveを追加する処理を書くのではなく、directiveで実装したいことを直接ngOnInit内に書く**
>   ＜コーディング例＞※Util.convertHAN2ZENは自作の関数です。import文などは省略しています。
>
> ```
>  element: HTMLElement;
>
>  constructor(private el: ElementRef,private renderer: Renderer2) {
>    this.element = this.el.nativeElement;
>  }
>
>  ngOnInit() {
>    const input = this.element.getElementsByTagName('input');
>     for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
>        if (input[i].getAttribute('name') === 'corp_name') {
>            fromEvent(input[i], 'blur')
>                .subscribe((event: any) => {
>                    const convertStr = Util.convertHAN2ZEN(event.target.value);
>                    this.renderer.setProperty(event.target, 'value', convertStr);
>                });
>        }
>    }
>  }
> ```
>
> **2.TSLintのカスタムルールを作る**
>   「指定のname属性の時に、指定のdirectiveが無ければコンパイルエラーを出す」様なカスタムルールをTSLintに作成すれば、directiveの実装漏れを防ぐ事が出来るのではないか。

確かにdirectiveの実装漏れを防ぐのが目的であれば、TSLintで良さそうです。
今回は「directiveの実装漏れを防ぐ」＋「実装者のコーディング量を少しでも減らす」＋「実装者がコントローラに対する装飾ルールを意識しないで済む仕組み」というのが目的だったので、1の案を採用することにしました。

ただ、name属性が必ずコントローラに記載されていなければならないので、そこはTSLintのカスタムルールを作って実装漏れが無い様にしたいと思っています。

また実際は、全てのコンポーネントのngOnInitに1の実装をするのではなく親クラスを作ってすべてのコンポーネントに継承させます。
必ず継承するルールにしたいので、ここもTSLintで制御したいです。

teratailユーザー：keisukehさんからも指摘がありましたが、親クラスのngOnInitをオーバーライドさせるのはアンチパターン(https://qiita.com/okunokentaro/items/90b60fae2622f7c1f1a2)となっているので、親クラスのメソッドを全てのコンポーネントのngOnInitで呼ぶつもりです。
(このやり方に問題がある様なら指摘頂けると嬉しいです。)

```
export class AppParent  {
    ngOnInit() {
        //何もしない
    }
    initialize(){
        //Formの初期化処理
    }
}

export class SampleComponent extends AppParent  implements OnInit {

ngOnInit() {
    this.initialize();
}
```